# Multiple instances of same function but dealing with different values

Tags: javascript, function, slider, range

I must apologize for my very basic knowledge of javascript, basically, I have three range sliders with different min/max values and I would like to change the text color of the output to show if that value is good or bad. The three functions below work fine individually with one slider but how can I combine them all together?

```
function checkValue() {
var x = document.getElementById("one");
var y = document.getElementById("oneOutput");
if (x.value >= 25) { y.style.color = "orange"; }
else if (x.value <= 8) { y.style.color = "red"; }
else { y.style.color = "green"; }
}

function checkValue() {
var x = document.getElementById("two");
var y = document.getElementById("twoOutput");
if (x.value >= 96) { y.style.color = "orange"; }
else if (x.value <= 91) { y.style.color = "red"; }
else { y.style.color = "green"; }
}

function checkValue() {
var x = document.getElementById("three");
var y = document.getElementById("threeOutput");
if (x.value >= 39.0) { y.style.color = "orange"; }
else if (x.value <= 34.9) { y.style.color = "red"; }
else { y.style.color = "green"; }
}
```

Many thanks,

Marc

Comment: What kind of things do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different name of function for each slider.

So, in your HTML code will be about like this:

```
<input id="one" type="range" oninput="checkValue1()" min=0 max=100 /><br>
<span id="oneOutput">Result 1</span>
<input id="two" type="range" oninput="checkValue2()" min=0 max=100 /><br>
<span id="twoOutput">Result 2</span>
<input id="three" type="range" oninput="checkValue3()" min=0 max=100 /><br>
<span id="threeOutput">Result 3</span>
```

Then, you just need to rename your function.

```
function checkValue1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("one");
    var y = document.getElementById("oneOutput");
    if (x.value >= 25) { y.style.color = "orange"; }
    else if (x.value <= 8) { y.style.color = "red"; }
    else { y.style.color = "green"; }
}

function checkValue2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("two");
    var y = document.getElementById("twoOutput");
    if (x.value >= 96) { y.style.color = "orange"; }
    else if (x.value <= 91) { y.style.color = "red"; }
    else { y.style.color = "green"; }
}

function checkValue3() {
    var x = document.getElementById("three");
    var y = document.getElementById("threeOutput");
    if (x.value >= 39.0) { y.style.color = "orange"; }
    else if (x.value <= 34.9) { y.style.color = "red"; }
    else { y.style.color = "green"; }
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can dry more your code by declaring some parameters to function.

```
function checkValue(id1, id2) {
 var x = document.getElementById(id1);
 var y = document.getElementById(id2);
 if (x.value >= 25) { y.style.color = "orange"; }
 else if (x.value <= 8) { y.style.color = "red"; }
 else { y.style.color = "green"; }
}
```

and then

```
<input onchange="checkValue('one', 'oneOutput')" />
<input onchange="checkValue('two', 'oneOutput')" />
<input onchange="checkValue('three', 'oneOutput')" />
```